# Powershell start process using call operator and passing custom credentials

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to execute DbUp application using Octopus deployment.

Instruction says to use this simple script:

```
& .\DbUp.exe | Write-Host
```

But the problem with that is I couldn't find the way to pass custom credentials to process start. I tried to use Process object directly:

```
"DbUp Deployment Script starting." | Write-Host
$pinfo.Username = $OctopusParameters['serviceCustomAccountName']
$pinfo.Domain = "DOMAIN"
$pinfo.Password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $OctopusParameters['serviceCustomAccountPassword'] -AsPlainText -Force)
$pinfo.FileName = "C:\DbUp.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = ""
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() 
$p.WaitForExit()
$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() | Write-Host
$p.StandardError.ReadToEnd() | Write-Host
"DbUp Deployment Script finished." | Write-Host
```

But this approach results with no StandardOutput being passed to Octopus log:

```
DbUp Deployment Script starting.
True
DbUp Deployment Script finished.
```

It seems to not execute the DbUp.exe at all because no changes are applied to database.

Is there a way to start process using call operator (& .\DbUp.exe) and passing custom credentials? If not, what might be the reason for Octopus not picking output form console app?

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath "path" -ArgumentList "arguments" -Credential (Get-Credential)` ?

Comment: @sodawillow: This one doesn't redirect console output to host even then using `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\DbUp.exe" -Credential ($creds) | Write-Host`

Comment: Does this work ? `Start-Process -FilePath "path" -ArgumentList "arguments" -Credential (Get-Credential) -RedirectStandardOutput "c:\test.txt"` And if you have logs, why do you need to redirerct `stdout`to console ?

Comment: No file is created when using Octopus, it is created when running script from ISE. I need to redirect to console so that Octopus deployment fail if necessary. All is printed when I'm using call operator.

Comment: It seems that all 3 methods prints output to Octopus when I don't pass custom credential. When I run ISE as the same account as Octopus everything is printed out as well. For some reason process is not started when using Octopus and custom account...

Comment: Why not run the whole script as a different user then ?

Comment: Users running Octopus and DbUp process have different rights. Octopus user can't have rights to connect to database.

Comment: Did you able to solve the issue? I have the same problem. If I run Start-Process with no new credentials it all works. If I pass new user credentials, Octopus does not print any output.

Strangely, if I do all this on my local computer I can capture the output even when passing new user credentials. It just does not work in Octopus environement.

Comment: @Vladimir sorry but no as I didn't look any further

Answer (score 0):

The powershell user context is associated with the user running the tentacle service, so that service can be admin and have db connection rights. The -NoNewWindow flag used with start-process should re-direct output to the same session.

Comment: This guys said he got it to work but had to use a couple more flags -PassThru -Wait and the -NoNewWindow
https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2016/09/run-a-console-application-with-powershell/

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer really addresses the OP's question or not, but it saved my hide when trying to execute a potentially long-running process from a PowerShell script step in my deployment process. If you want to kick off a long-running process from an Octopus Deploy Script Step and have the deployment continue, then don't use the `-NoNewWindow` parameter to `Start-Process`.